# What is wrong with saying hope you have a nice day? In the English language is it considerd rude in anyway? Please tell me your thoughts

Tags: word-choice

Someone I know had told me hi hope you have a nice day then. quite talking 
Rude, or not rude?

Comment: Have a nice day is not a rude comment.  In recent years a comedian ([George Carlin](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xJZ6ixiVgCs)) did a bit on it and essentially said, "What if I don't want to have a nice day?" I think this gave later rise to the tongue-in-cheek, "Have the day you're gonna have." (Maybe in the movie Freaky Friday with Jamie Lee Curtis)  But anyone who takes "Have a nice day" as in any way rude is an idiot if the well-wisher is sincere.

Comment: Who told you this?  Friend, acquaintance, or cashier?  What does "then. quite talking" mean? That the person stopped talking to you?  What was the occasion?  A party? A check-out line at the grocery?  Context is everything.

Comment: A friend said as soon as they got on the phone then quit talking.

Comment: So you called a friend and said, "Hi, it's Cory."  Your friend then said "Hi.  I hope you have a nice day" and hung up.  Have I got that right?

Answer (score 1):

[Have a nice day!](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/have_a_nice_day?rdfrom=Have%20a%20nice%20day)

> *Have a nice day* is used as a salutation similar in meaning to goodbye.
>   *Have a nice day* is a commonly spoken valediction, typically spoken by service employees or clerks to customers at the end of a transaction, particularly in North America. This repetitious and dutifully polite usage has resulted in the phrase developing a cultural connotation as a stereotypical display of impersonality, disinterest, or passive-aggressive behavior.

So, It could mean: *Get out of my face!* , but that's just a possibility. Depends on the context and the history of your relationship and other things.

Comment: In ordinary social situations, "Have a nice day" never means "Get out of my face!"  Service personnel have certainly made this a dutiful equivalent of "goodbye" but where do you get the idea that its "cultural connotation" is one of passive-aggressive behavior?

Comment: @deadrat From the Wiktionary link that is offered in the answer, and also (perhaps not very reliable, but) from [this link](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Have+a+Nice+Day). Again, it's just a possibility.

Comment: Oh, dear.  The Urban Dictionary from ten years ago.  It is certainly possible that "Have a nice day" could be used sarcastically.  But that's true of just about anything.  I can certainly conjure up a scenario where an interaction  ends with the phrase used in a rude or passive aggressive manner.  But not in ordinary conversation.  It's never happened to me, and I'm a jerk.

Comment: Yeah, UD is not a reliable source even (especially?) for new entries, let alone older ones. UD  is _crowdsourced_ and doesn't seem to be moderated; (certainly not as much as, say, Wiktionary—which has its shortcomings, but at least tries to admit them; e.g. lack of sources in an article)

Comment: I see that Wiktionary offers HAND as a "synonym", for Have a Nice Day, not as an "acronym".  (Did a double-take there!) Again, Wiktionary is not a very reliable dictionary. (I was going to say "not a real dictionary", but that would hack off Wiktionary fans as well as linguistic relativists.  Let's just say it has its place among other sources, and that place is not pre-eminent.)

Comment: Many dictionaries (Longman, The Free Dictionary, Macmillan, etc.) point out the fact that this expression is said especially to customers in shops and restaurants when they are leaving (maybe in AmE especially). So granted is that it is more likely to be used to imply dismissal and rejection and unfriendliness, than _Goodbye_ , _God bless_ etc. For example, there's a hard rock song on YouTube (uploaded six years ago) with 30 million views, named _Have a Nice Day_, that goes: _When the world gets in my face, I say "Have A Nice Day!"_.

Comment: All I'm saying is when you call someone and they pick up and say _Hi! Hope you have a nice day!_ and hang up on you (see the comment below the OP), there's a _possibility_ that you've been offended, and in situations like this, this valediction is more or less liable to be used in an unfriendly way. (About UD I have a lot to say, but it'd be off-topic here)